# What version of Gazebo for ROS 2 foxy fitzroy on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am a new user of ROS 2 and of course of Gazebo as well so there might be some concepts I do not have clear.
I have checked the Gazebo installation tutorials with ROS, but I do not see any mention about foxy fitzroy version. The latest one I see is Eloquent (with  Gazebo 9.x).
Is there any tutorial to install Gazebo with ROS2 foxy fitzroy?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25559/what-version-of-gazebo-for-ros-2-foxy-fitzroy-on-ubuntu-20.04?/) by [jeferrandiz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/29054/jeferrandiz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The official Gazebo version supported with Foxy is 11. This is defined on [REP-2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#foxy-fitzroy-may-2020-may-2023).

If you already have Foxy installed, you can just install this additional package to get everything you need:

`sudo apt install ros-foxy-gazebo-ros-pkgs`

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1